# Arduino binary serial data input

Tags: arduino

I have a serial stream that I'm trying to read and get some variables from it.
The input is serial, 9600, eight data bits, no parity with two stop bits. The data is binary.

So a incoming byte may look like `00001001`. Contained within this are three variables.
0 is the first, 000 is the second and 1001 is the third.

The first works out if this message is for us (it's an ID, there are only two ID's). The second tells us what position the data is for (we are building a four digit decimal number). The third tells us what the data is for that position in hex.

So, 00001001 = 9xxx

To make 9999 for ID#1 the binary stream would look like this
00001001000110010010100100111001

Where do I start? How do I store the data into variables?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted to do this endlessly:

```
byte id         = 0;
byte digit      = 0;
char data[2][4] = { { -1, -1, -1, -1 },        // data[id][digit]
                    { -1, -1, -1, -1 } };      // -1 means has yet to be set

while (true)                                   // endless read loop
{
  if (Serial.available())                      // check if it is for us
  {
    id = Serial.peek() >> 7;
    digit = (Serial.peek() & 0x7F) >> 4;       // get data position
    if (digit < 4) 
    {
      data[id][digit] = Serial.read() & 0x0F;  // store data
    }
  }

  // Do your stuff with the data here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably set the bit-fields in a struct.

```
struct Packet {
   unsigned short nId       : 1;    // 1 bit
   unsigned short nPosition : 3;    // 3 bits
   unsigned short nData     : 4;    // 4 bits
};
```

Then you can access it with the struct

```
struct Packet pac;

pac = Serial.Read(); // However you get your serial packet

print(pac.nId);      // A printout of ID
```